# mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError with django

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am trying to build a django rest framework application with mongodb backnd , for which I am using mongoengine. According to issues #[935](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/935) of mongoengine (closed already in github) say, had to go down to the version of mongoengine and that of pymongo for django. Then my versions are as follows:

- pymongo 2.8,
- mongoengine 0.9,
- python 2.7,
- django 1.10

I have configured settings.py according to the documentation of mongoengine 0.9, however I have this connection error, I would appreciate some help, @mongoengine @contributors

```html
<p>lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 126, in get_connection
    raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
command SON([('saslStart', 1), ('mechanism', 'SCRAM-SHA-1'), ('autoAuthorize', 1), ('payload', Binary('n,,n=mongo,r=MzYxNTkyNzU5Njg4', 0))]) on namespace formkeep_db.$cmd failed: Authentication failed.
</p>
```

lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 126, in get_connection
    raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
command SON([('saslStart', 1), ('mechanism', 'SCRAM-SHA-1'), ('autoAuthorize', 1), ('payload', Binary('n,,n=mongo,r=MzYxNTkyNzU5Njg4', 0))]) on namespace formkeep_db.$cmd failed: Authentication failed.

Comment: Authentication failed. Check your username and password.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake, I accidentally removed --auth from the mongodb server startup command, so authentication stopped working ;)

Comment: @Lily, can you answer your solution